# Regex to match all permutations of {1,2,3} with repetition in the middle. Ex: 122223

Tags: regex

I need a *regex* expression, which will search for all permutations of digits (1, 2, 3), where digit in the middle will occur one or many times.

**For ex:**

123

133332

21111113

312

13333332

I've tried this expression:

```
([1][2]+[3])|([1][3]+[2])|([2][1]+[3])|([2][3]+[1])|([3][2]+[1])|([3][1]+[2]))
```

Unfortunately it is slow, is there any way to make it more more efficient?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
([1-3])(?!\1)([1-3])\2*(?!\1|\2)[1-3]
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/67pnRX/2)

**Details**

- `([1-3])` - Group 1: `1`, `2` or `3`
- `(?!\1)([1-3])\2*` - a digit from `1` to `3` not equal to Group 1 value and then 0+ occurrences of the digit
- `(?!\1|\2)[1-3]` - a digit from `1` to `3` not equal to Group 1 and 2 value

In case you need to match the whole string, add `^` at the start and `$` at the end of the pattern.

Comment: Thanks for helping, it is pretty fast, but could it be even faster, because it is not applicable for my solution

Comment: @SultanSaliev I doubt you can have a better *regex* solution.